# To create various elements on an image that point to different webpages

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a requirement where if I have have an image of a fruit bowl which has apple, banana, grapes and when a mouse is moved over apple and clicked on apple it must take me to a different webpage, if I click on banana it must take me to a different webpage and the same for grapes.

But it must still be a single image or must look like single image for the viewer, I hope you got my point. Basically an image and based on what part of the image is being clicked it must take me to that page.

Is this possible is my first question, if yes then how is it possible what are the tools that are required for it.

Comment: First tool you need is knowledges, as I see...

Comment: three images stack together

Comment: The first thing that popped my mind is that clearly you need irregular (polygonal) hoverable shaped areas (tracing a specific fruit - part of the image). What have you googled?

Answer (score 3):

It would be simplest to use the `<map>` HTML element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map

This example shows two circlular, clickable areas, overlaying an image:

```html
<map name="primary">
  <area shape="circle" coords="75,75,75" href="left.html">
  <area shape="circle" coords="275,75,75" href="right.html">
</map>
<img usemap="#primary" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="350 x 150 pic">
```

Comment: so if I have to use this image as my banner can I still use the above code? I mean I should just have to increase the resolution of it am I right?

Answer (score -2):

I think what you need is to create an image map, which will give you links you need.